# Insert data from remote client file into DB2 table

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have a .txt file in my local workspace, I am trying to insert data from that file into a DB2 table using below query but its throwing an error.

Data in the file is partitioned.

```
load from C:\Data\VALIDATION_CALC_RX.txt of asc modified by striptblanks reclen=126
method L (1 5,6 55,56 56,57 58,59 87,88 116,117 126)
insert into CALCULATE (ID, NAME, ADDRESS, COUNTRY, STATE, ZIP_CODE, LAST_DTM);
```

`Error: Lookup Error  -  SQL3126N  Remote client requires absolute path for files and directories.`

Please provide a solution,

thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `load client from...` -- that's as much as I can suggest without you providing any details.

Comment: I voted mustaccio's recommended solution: "load client from..." as it worked for me.  I was able to keep the .csv file on my local computer even tho the database is remote.

Answer (score 1):

This error is occurring because you are connecting to a remote database on a server, but attempting to load a file which is local to your machine.

When the server looks for the file `C:\Data\VALIDATION_CALC_RX.txt`, it is looking on it's own `C:` drive, not your `C:` drive.

You need to transfer the file to the server first. Or serve the file from your machine, and refer to the file on your machine from the server's point of view (`\\yourmachine\path\to\file.txt`).

Comment: I have placed the file in the server and executed the below command  
load from /tmp/tstfldr/VLDTN_CALC_RX.txt of asc modified by striptblanks reclen=126 method L (1 5,6 55,56 56,57 58,59 87,88 116,117 126) insert into CALCULATE (ID, NAME, ADDRESS, COUNTRY, STATE, ZIP_CODE, LAST_DTM);    It executed for few minutes but data was not loaded in the table.

Comment: No messages? It is hard to diagnose when you only say that no data was loaded. Try adding a `MESSAGES "C:\tmp\tstfldr\load_message.txt"` parameter.